# Forms - Foreign Key - ModelChoiceField - NOT SAVING

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 accounts, Instructor & Student which both extend a CustomUser model. Instructors have an email field. Students have an instructor key that they select from a drop-down menu.

I am able to populate the ModelChoiceField with instructor's emails, no problem. However, I am now unable to save the selected instructor's email into the foreign key appropriately. I think the error lies in how I save the instructor_id, specifically this line,

```
student.instructor_id = Instructor.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data["instructor_id"])
```

, but I'm not sure what the problem is. Please help!

**forms.py**

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    instructor_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Instructor.objects.all())

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'inGameName', 'instructor_id')
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'Required',
            'inGameName': 'Required; A name by which you can be identified',
            'instructor_id': 'Optional; Provided by your professor',
        }

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.instructor_id = Instructor.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data["instructor_id"])
        student.save()
        user.save()
        return user


class InstructorSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Your Email', help_text='Required')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username',  'inGameName', 'email')
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'Required',
            'inGameName': 'Required; A name by which you can be identified',
        }

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_instructor = True
        instructor = Instructor.objects.create(user=user)
        instructor.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        instructor.save()
        user.save()
        return user
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager as AbstractUserManager
from django.db import models


class UserManager(AbstractUserManager):
    pass


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_instructor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True, default='')
    inGameName = models.CharField("In-Game Name", max_length=40, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

class Instructor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, default='USER', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, default='USER', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    instructor_id = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, to_field='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

Comment: This is a bit all over the place. Why have you used `email` as the to_field for the foreign key? Why have you called it `instructor_id` (and not just `instructor`)?

Comment: I wanted the instructor's email specifically to be the link between the instructors.

Comment: Perhaps in your `class StudentSignUpForm` you might want to change the model inside the meta class from `CustomUser` to `Student`

Comment: Doing so causes the error 'Unknown field(s) (username, inGameName) specified for Student'